# Single (accented) characters with `str.__len__(x) == 2`

Tags: python-3.6

To the best of my understanding, `str.__len__(x)` counts accented characters double in Python 2 because of their byte representation, but once in Python 3, although I couldn't find proper documentation on `str.__len__` on python.org.

[Python documentation on stdtypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

[Python documentation on len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

However, If I run the following on Google Colab, the `str.__len__(..)` is counted as `2`

[image: example]

```
import sys

test = u'ö'

print(type(test), len(test), sys.version)
```

Where is `str.__len__` documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to represent the symbol "ö" in Unicode. One is as U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS. The other is U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O followed by U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS. If you restrict your source files to ASCII these can be represented as `"\u00f6"` and `"o\u0308"` respectively.

In the first case, I get a length of 1. In the second case, I get a length of 2. (Tested with Python 3.7.2). I suspect your code is using the second representation.

This matches the [documentation for the string type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) which notes that "Strings are immutable **sequences of Unicode code points**" (emphasis mine). A representation that consists of two code points would therefore have a length of 2.

You can use the [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) function to convert between the two forms. Using `"NFC"` for the form parameter will convert to the composed representation (length 1), using `"NFD"` will decompose it into a letter and a combining character (length 2).

Comment: This is most certainly the correct answer. I don't know Python, but there is most likely a way to convert between different normalization forms (see http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Normalization_Forms_Table)

Comment: @erikkallen - good point, added a description of how to do the conversion in Python.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation of this on python.org?

Comment: @Herbert - the documentation does define a string as a sequence of Unicode code points, so that would naturally imply a representation that consists of 2 code points would have a length of 2. I've added the relevant link into the answer.